# Looping through a table to send emails

Tags: sql, loops, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a table and execute and email once a field changes.  So, in the table, I have the following...

`Name   Num   Flag   ID   Email`

```
A12     1     A     42   steve@yahoo.com
A13     1     A     42   steve@yahoo.com
A15     1     A     85   Joe@yahoo.com
```

Now, the number of rows can be WAY BIGGER or much smaller.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a loop, in peoplecode, that will allow me to send "steve" an email once I hit a row with a different email.   The table is ordered so I don't have to worry about those issues.

Any assistance or thoughts on planning this are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered aggregating your result set?

For example, this would give you a result set that only has one row for each distinct email:

```
SELECT Email 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Email
```

If there are additional fields you need to distinquish records by, you can add them to the group by clause.

If the result set you are using already has a lot of filtering, you might consider something like putting it into a temp table, and then selecting the aggregated emails from that temp table.

Comment: No I haven't but, your example doesn't allow for multiple rows in an email.... does it?  All of the fields, except for the email field, I'm trying to send in an email to the address in the last column.  So, if there are 12 rows with your email address, I want to send you 1 email, with all 12 rows of data.  Does that make more sense or am I still missing what you are suggesting?